# Cannot preview in this file - SwiftUI Testing.app may have crashed

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I got this error after launching Xcode 11 beta with a newly upgrade OS whenever I tried previewing (Resume button). Preview not working.

Answer (score 1):

Solution was to make sure Command Line Tools were set to Xcode 11 in

```
Preferences -> Locations -> Command Line Tools
```

Comment: Just FYI, you're being downvoted by people because you're not allowed to discuss Apple's beta software on public forums! You in fact risk loosing your developer license as you agree to not discuss or share info about any beta software. However on a personal note I want to thank you for the help!

Comment: @simonthumper Thank you for the tip. I didn't even think about that, and I guess you're right. But that also means that any developer here on this forum risk the same. Apple dev world is buzzing with excitement about swiftui, working hard to figure things out and helping each other. Would be a strange thing for Apple to punish us for that, even though they might *legally* be able to... ‍♂

Comment: Yeah I realised that shortly after posting this... perhaps they've changed their approach this year, but I'm unsure why else you'd have got downvoted for asking a perfectly legitimate question! 

Comment: AFAIK, they got rid of the NDA a few years ago. I think it's now ok to discuss beta software after WWDC.